# Cordova File Transfer plugin to download a file to iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, file-transfer

I'm using below code to download and sava a file in my phone storage.

```
    var downloadUrl = encodeURI(cordova.file.dataDirectory + fileName);
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileTransfer.download(
    "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png",
    downloadUrl,
    function(entry) {
    alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },

    function(error) {
    alert("download error source " + error.source);
    alert("download error target " + error.target);
    alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    });
```

This code is working fine on any android device but doesn’t work in iPhone giving the following error.

```
    download error source " the url used"
    download error target: " the target used "
    upload error code 1
```

I’m new to iOS and Can someone help me to solve this issue? And let me know any permissions that should be granted before executing this code...

Answer (score 2):

The File Transfer Plugin has been deprecated for a while (over a year), and you should probably not invest too much time getting the File Transfer plugin to work.  I would recommend following the instructions in the blog post on how to [transition off the file api](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html).

So for your code (untested, but should work):

```
window.requestFileSystem(cordova.file.dataDirectory, 0, function (fs) {
    console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
    fs.root.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        console.log('fileEntry is file? ' + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Make sure you add the domain name to the Content-Security-Policy <meta> element.
        oReq.open("GET", "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png", true);
        // Define how you want the XHR data to come back
        oReq.responseType = "blob";
        oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
            var blob = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
            if (blob) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

                    fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
                        console.log("Successful file write...");                        
                    };

                    fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                        console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
                    };

                    fileWriter.write(blob);
                });
            } else {
                console.error('we didnt get an XHR response!');
            }
        };
        oReq.send(null);
    }, function (err) { 
        console.error('error getting file! ' + err); 
    });
}, function (err) { 
    console.error('error getting persistent fs! ' + err); 
});
```

Comment: when I use `cordova.file.dataDirectory` i get an error `wrong type of parameter type of requestFileSystem: expected number, but got string`.  And then when I change it to `localFileSystem.PERSISTENT` - it seemingly works, but then I can't find the file anywhere

Comment: according to the documents for `LocalFileSystem` that method is outdated, then it refers to the `cordova-plugin-file` plugin, which under `Supported Systems` says `These platforms do not support FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer nor FileWriter.write(blob).`

Comment: Here I am, back at this post over 2 years later.  The above doesn't work...as atested to by the many users posting on the very blog that provided the above solution.  Alas, it looks like `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` is officially dead.  Not certain what I am going to do now.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working in iOS I had to put the create() in a platform ready check.

```
constructor(platform: Platform, filetransfer: FileTransfer) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.Transfer = filetransfer.create();
    }
}

download(fileName){

    let lLocation = this.file.cacheDirectory + fileName;

    this.Transfer.download(
    "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png",
    lLocation).then().catch
}
```